# ASP.NET MVC Grid controls comparison

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

There seems to be many grid controls for MVC, but I can't find any comparison between them i.e. which one is better over another one. Some support `server-side data binding` and some support `client-side data binding`. I found the following.

1. Are client-side binding grids better than the server-side ones?
2. Are the jQuery grid controls better than the controls like WebGrid?

Could you help me choose one among these with reasons for the same? I need `Ajax support`, `paging`, `sorting` etc (not inline grid editing, though no harm if that functionality is available) and also I need to be able to `define templated columns` like gridview for some of the columns.

1. [Webgrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx)
2. [MVC contrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/)
3. [MVC controls toolkit](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/)
4. [jQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

Comment: try also jquery.dataTables http://datatables.net/

Answer (score 6):

Your list doesn't include the free Telerik controls for MVC found [here](http://telerik.com/free)

The grid control supports, templating, AJAX, sorting, filtering, paging etc. It's an absolutely amazing grid. I can't speak for the others, but I strongly suggest you evaluate Telerik before making a decision.

Check out the MVC demos [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid)

**Edit:** One of the main reasons I love this grid is because AJAX functionality isn't treated as a second class citizen. You can perform all the same functionality that you can using server binding.

**Update 12/2013**

The free Telerik controls have been deprecated in favor of Kendo UI. However you can still download the free controls and view their documentation.

I still use this from time to time. I can't justify paying for Kendo for small projects as the controls are very similar.

[Documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor)

[Controls](http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks. can I use this for an intranet web application (licensing)?

Comment: That's a good question, and I think the best way to find out is to contact Telerik (With more details of your application of course).

Comment: For intranet, it should be okay. Their MVC stuff is licensed under GPL 2, so it only becomes an issue if you start redistributing your software (as far as I'm aware, not a lawyer). http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/aspnet-mvc.aspx

Comment: I read the Telerik site, and I can't find any free grid there, so if you can point to the exact page it will be helpful. Thanks
To give a personal opinion, I used the jqGrid and it's really powerful, but sometimes is hard to configure.

Comment: try any other but don't try telerik.

Comment: @R.DarioDuarte It's been replaced by KendoUI, but you can find the download link here: http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/ Also, Abu, your opinion is your own, but please offer an explanation why you don't like Telerik. At this point you're just being a troll.

Comment: @AbuHamzah That comment is certainly not in the spirit of StackOverflow and neither is it of any help or value at all.

Answer (score 4):

Which grid is the best one for you...depends on your specifications...I will not enter in the comparison among the grids...since I am the author of the Mvc Controls Toolkit grid...so my opinion would be biased :)

However, I can give you an idea on how to compare your specs against the features of the grids discussig how to choose between server side and client side bindings:
1) First of all BOTH of them are useful...depending on the problem to be faced
2) You said you need paging and sorting...now do you prefer sending all data to the client and then to let it pages and sorts all data received or you prefer doing this operation on the server and sending to the client JUST ONE PAGE OF DATA? For big amount of data just the second option is acceptable...but for small amout of data all two choices are viable depending on the application needs. Now if you would like performing sorting and paging on the server side...a server side binding is better.

If you decide for client side bindings an acceptable choice is jQGrid...or some other purely javascript grid. If you would like to customize the grid features...with say columns, or rows templates, then you have to consider using software based on knockout.js

The Mvc Controls Toolkit has both 2 kinds of sever side binding grids, and give you the opportunity to customize a client side grid by using Client Blocks and the ClientBlockRepeater

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to send all data to the client. that is inefficient. only the current page data is enough.

Comment: so probably it is better a grid that can be bound server side! The advantages of client side bound grids are:
1) they send just json data, so there is a bandwidth gain if a lot of data need to be sent to the client...but it is not your case
2) you can customize user editing of data with the help of js since you have everything on the client...but you don't need editing so...
3)there are more free client side grid than free server side bound grids.
Since you don't need in line editing probably the WebGrid is enough for you....it is completely free...no license restrictions Already tried it?